# How to deploy a specific django folder in a repository to an azure app service?

Tags: django, azure, web-deployment

I have a Github repository with the folders `back-end` and `front-end`. The folder `back-end` contains a folder `custom-site`, which contains a Django project.

I would like to use Azure to deploy this Django project, but it seems that Azure only attempts to deploy the root folder of the repository. How do I indicate that the `back-end/custom-site/` folder should be used as root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future purposes:

I fixed it by changing the yml file. More specifically I modified the path in the section on uploading the artifact for deployment jobs.

```
- name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
  with:
    name: python-app
    path: ./path/to/your/directory/
```